# Loop MP3 precisely iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

what is the best possibility to achieve a gapless loop of an MP3? Currently I am using AVAudioPlayer and set the .numberOfLoops() property to -1 but it is hearable, that the track restarts. That is not the case, when the Track is played with e.g. Adobe Audition.

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating two instances of the AVAudioPlayer and then when the first one stops, immediately start the second one.

While the second one is playing, rewind and queue the first one and then when the second one finishes, start the first one. Repeat.

Once thing to watch out for - are you sure that the MP3 is "gapless" ie. just make sure there is no silence at the beginning or end of the track in order to achieve a seamless loop.